Can a sanyasi give Diksha of any devata mantra?
Recently I have seen that puri Shankaracharya gives any devata mantra Diksha. Therefore can a sanyasi give mantra Diksha of any devata and which shastra tells/supports this practice?

It's possible for an elevated Siddha (enlightened being) to invoke any Deity / Mantra and also initiate others in any Mantra Sadhana as per the inclination and qualification of the disciple.
